# FFmpeg: Make video appear after x seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video clip that I use as a background, then another clip that contains some text, is there a way to make this second clip start
playing after `x` seconds?

```
background: 00:00:00|-------------------|00:00:05
foreground: 00:00:02|         >---------|00:00:05
                              ^it starts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamps of the overlay have to be shifted and overlay filter has to be told to delay start of overlay.

Basic form of command is

```
ffmpeg -i base -itsoffset X -i overlay -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable='gt(t\,X)'" output
```

Audio processing and encoding will use default parameters.